# Pandas DataFrame checking condition before a specific row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4SpL.png)

I have the above DataFrame with millions of rows and wish to groupby(['Instrument', 'Date']) for some data analysis.

I wish to compare the last row of each group with the Value before, which is the first to be equal or exceed the Value of the last row. For instance, as shown in the Image, Instrument AAD on Date 4/18/2012 has a Value of 32437.5, at Time 9:59:44 AM. The first to exceed or equal that Value is at Time 9:42:39 AM with a Value of 37491.87 --> this is the result that I want.

If I wish to code with Pandas Python, may I know what code is best for this scenario?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you paste your dataframe into your question so we can copy and paste it?

Comment: More information about your dataframe will help. I suppose what you need is the shift function of pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work,

```
def f(grp):

  return grp.loc[(grp>=grp.iloc[-1])].iloc[0]

res = df.groupby(['Instrument', 'Date'])['Value'].agg(lambda x: f(x))
res.head()
```

If you are not certain that always there's going to be a value higher than last row, use the following `f()`.

```
def f(grp):
  try:
    return grp.loc[(grp>=grp.iloc[-1])].iloc[0]
  except IndexError:
    return np.nan
```

Comment: Btw, what if I want to include the Time column in the DataFrame? What can I do to the code? I tried res = df.groupby(['Instrument', 'Date'])['Value', 'Time].agg(lambda x: f(x)) but it doesn't work. I think mainly because of the "agg".

Comment: Also, can you explain briefly the logic of this code? Why use agg? I always though agg is for aggregate, i.e. sum()

Comment: @ShaunLim, you cannot use `Time` because that's the axis you groupby. And why I use agg, because agg is used whenever you want to reduce your each group in the dataframe to a single row which is what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you edited the dataframe for the last value to become the first in order to compare against it, or you created some sort of temporary array/buffer to store and compare the values, you'd have to run two checks, first to find the final row of the group, then to find the first overtaking value in the group. I recommend you create an array, storing the values of the group, then taking the last value and running a 'while not' statement

```
group = [1,2,3,4,5,6,3]

overtake = False
while not overtake:
  for i in group:
    if group[i] >= group[-1]:
        overtake_value = group[i]
        overtake = True
        break
print(overtake_value)

>> 3
```

You just need a way to get the column of values in the group assigned to temporary array for this method to work

edit note: the array/list should contain the entries of the values of the group, meaning only a 1 dimensional array.